# Arranging several items in one or two lines depending on their size

Tags: spacing, horizontal-alignment, titles

I want to set title pages in a way that is google scholar compliant, that is, the title has to be huge, the author names should be large but smaller then the title. I had a solution where I just listed the authornames separated with a colon, but the authors complained. They need there affiliations on the title page because of funding and evalutaion issues. So, the solution I came up with is to put author and affiliation in a tabular environment and put these tabular environments into one line and put a `\hfill`to the left, between the authors and to the right. However, this fails for papers with many authors. See example.

Is there a way to create title pages automatically that put two or three authors in one line, if the space permits this and if space does not permit this a new line is started and authors are centered there? So for five names, I would like to get something like A B C in one line with equal space between the authors and the margins and then D E on the next line. If a new line is started, there should be vertical space between the new line and the previous line and the new line should not start at the left margin.

For very long author names it should be 1 or 2 authors per line.

This is what I have:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
        \usepackage{hyperref}
        \setcounter{page}{393}
        \begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\begin{center}
  {\huge\bf Constraint-Based RMRS Construction from Shallow Grammars\par}

  \bigskip

~\\
  \hfill\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}c@{}}

                {\LARGE  Anette Frank}\\{\small DFKI Saarbrücken}\end{tabular}\hfill~\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}c@{}}

                {\LARGE  Kathrin Spreyer}\\{\small DFKI Saarbrücken}\end{tabular}\hfill~\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}c@{}}

                {\LARGE  Witold Drożdżyński}\\{\small DFKI Saarbrücken}\end{tabular}\hfill~\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}c@{}}

                {\LARGE  Hans-Ulrich Krieger}\\{\small DFKI Saarbrücken}\end{tabular}\hfill~\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}c@{}}

                {\LARGE  Ulrich Schäfer}\\{\small DFKI Saarbrücken}\end{tabular}\hfill\mbox{}\par

  \vspace*{3\bigskipamount}

  Proceedings of the 11th International Conference on\par Head-Driven Phrase Structure Grammar

  \bigskip

  Center for Computational Linguistics, Katholieke Universiteit Leuven

  \medskip

  Stefan Müller (Editor)

  \medskip

  2004

  \medskip

  CSLI Publications

  \medskip

  pages 393--413

  \medskip

  \url{http://csli-publications.stanford.edu/HPSG/2004}
\end{center}

\vfill
\noindent
Frank, Anette, Spreyer, Kathrin, Drożdżyński, Witold, Krieger, Hans-Ulrich, \& Schäfer, Ulrich. (2004). Constraint-Based RMRS Construction from Shallow Grammars. In Stefan Müller (Ed.): \emph{Proceedings of the 11th International Conference on Head-Driven Phrase Structure Grammar, Center for Computational Linguistics, Katholieke Universiteit Leuven} (pp.\ 393--413). Stanford, CA: CSLI Publications.

 \end{document}
```

Comment: "google scholar compliant": suddenly I feel like belonging to an antic world; truly a passing of ages...

Comment: "smartphone compliant" is probably the next thing I will have to digest :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well, this does what you ask for I think:

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
        \usepackage{hyperref}
        \setcounter{page}{393}
        \begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}

\newcommand\formatauthor[2]{\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}c@{}}
  {\LARGE#1\strut}\\
  {\small#2\strut}\\
  \rule{\dimexpr0.5\linewidth-1em}{0pt}
  \end{tabular}\xhfill\ignorespaces}
\newcommand\xhfill{\hspace{1em plus 1fill}}

\begin{center}
  {\huge\bfseries Constraint-Based RMRS Construction from Shallow Grammars\par}

\vspace*{4ex}

\begingroup
\setlength{\leftskip}{0pt plus 1fill}
\setlength{\rightskip}{0pt plus 1fill}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\setlength{\parfillskip}{0pt}
  \formatauthor{Anette Frank}{DFKI Saarbrücken}
  \formatauthor{Kathrin Spreyer}{DFKI Saarbrücken}
  \formatauthor{Witold Drożdżyński}{DFKI Saarbrücken}
  \formatauthor{Hans-Ulrich Krieger}{DFKI Saarbrücken}
  \formatauthor{Ulrich Schäfer}{DFKI Saarbrücken}
\par\endgroup

  \vspace*{8ex}

  Proceedings of the 11th International Conference on\par Head-Driven Phrase Structure Grammar

  \bigskip

  Center for Computational Linguistics, Katholieke Universiteit Leuven

  \medskip

  Stefan Müller (Editor)

  \medskip

  2004

  \medskip

  CSLI Publications

  \medskip

  pages 393--413

  \medskip

  \url{http://csli-publications.stanford.edu/HPSG/2004}
\end{center}

\vfill
\noindent
Frank, Anette, Spreyer, Kathrin, Drożdżyński, Witold, Krieger, Hans-Ulrich, \& Schäfer, Ulrich. (2004). Constraint-Based RMRS Construction from Shallow Grammars. In Stefan Müller (Ed.): \emph{Proceedings of the 11th International Conference on Head-Driven Phrase Structure Grammar, Center for Computational Linguistics, Katholieke Universiteit Leuven} (pp.\ 393--413). Stanford, CA: CSLI Publications.

 \end{document}
```

Some remarks:

- You should define a command for things you repeat, like I did with `\formatauthor`.
- Don't use `~\\` for vertical spacing, use `\vspace*` instead.
- The added `\strut` make sure that all author blocks render with the same line height.
- I modified the spacing a bit, it looks nicer to me.
- The added invisible rule `\rule{\dimexpr0.5\linewidth-1em}{0pt}` makes the names to be at most two on one line (which may be frowned upon), but it achieves them to be verically aligned. You can remove it, but then you lose the vertical alignment.
- Do not use `\bf` please, it's obsolete, and it should be replaced by `\bfseries`.

Comment: Can you remove `\bf`?